# Yii Model Relation Join (HAS_ONE)

Tags: mysql, yii, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I want a basic syntax of relation and their parameters

i need these clarification

- Difference Between BELONGS_TO and HAS_ONE ?
- I want to use the relation on CGridView (That relation refers the another table element as a Foreign key )
  For Eg 
  I have Three tables
- Messenger
- UserLogin
- Userprofile

I am in Messenger Admin Grid
I have Primary key of UserLogin table
That userlogin have userprofile Primary key
Now i want to access the userProfile fields in my grid

i already try the (through) in relation like

### its in Messenger model

```
    'relationeg'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'Userprofile',array('user_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'user'),
'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserLogin','user_id'),
```

i access this on my grid

```
    .....
    ....
array(
    'name'=>'message_by',
    'value'=>'$data->relationeg->username'
),
....
...
```

But i got the wrong data's that are totally differ by the key of base table record

i have doubt on this line

```
'relationeg'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'Userprofile',array('user_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'user'),
```

in this self::HAS_ONE means?
when i add the where condition of the join query how will add the condition on this

Advance thanks

Your answer welcome

Comment: This is documented in [The Definitive Guide to Yii - Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr). You can enable the query logging and see what queries get generated for each relation type.

Comment: about relations you can check this wiki: [has_one vs belongs_to](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/)

Comment: Thanks Dcoder and Adler i resolve this . Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KEY POINT :** A BELONGS_TO relation says that a field in this model points to the primary key in another model; in this case, the current model owns the linking field.

**KEY POINT :** A HAS_ONE relation says that some other model has a linking field pointing to this model's primary key; in this case, the related model owns the linking field.

We can thik that a PARENT table will be the one that doesn't have a foreign key, and a CHILD table as the one who "depends" on the parent table, that is, it has a foreign key.

Given that, a CHILD **BELONGS_TO** a PARENT and a PARENT **HAS_ONE** CHILD.

The answer is [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/)